# How can I handle empty object property using php

Tags: php, object

I am reading object property like this:

`$lat = $data['location']['latLng']['latitude'];`

Sometimes `['latLng']` or `['latitude']` doesnt exist.

I want to put null into `$lat` variable instead of php warning. How can I do this?

I tryied:

```
function getKey ($data, $path) {
    return array_key_exists ($path, $data) ? $data[$path] : null;
}

$lat = getKey($data, ['location']['latLng']['longitudqqqse'])
```

But it is same.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why not just use `$lat = $data['location']['latLng']['latitude']??null;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the null coalescing operator, for example:

```php
$lat = $data['location']['latLng']['latitude'] ?? null;
$lng = $data['location']['latLng']['longitude'] ?? null;
```

You can see some more examples in the php 7 migration docs:
https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php